# Firefox zooms own website

Tags: html, css, ajax, firefox, zooming

I just can't get behind this.

I'm writing a website in html,ajax,php,css and on chrome everything just looks fine like it should.
Opening the site in firefox gives the impression that the site is zoomed in about 120%. But the zoom level in firefox is at 100% and when I change it manually to 80% the website is shown correctly.

I tried several things like changing the layout.css.devPixelsPerPx property in firefox,checking my css-code and so on - no result. However it's just my website that seems to be zoomed other sites on the web appear totally normal.
Does anyone of you guys already had the same issue and knows a solution?
Thanks.

UPDATE:
Fixed it. I was trusting Chrome blindly. In the end the default zoom in Chrome was at 75%. So Chrome was the problem. Thx anyway :)

Comment: and this happens only on Firefox?

Comment: Post your code sample or make a http://www.jsfiddle.net. Thanks.

Comment: Run Firefox in sandbox mode (no plugins/extensions) and see if you get the same results.  Also test using Firefox on a different PC to see if it's your local install affecting it

Comment: Could you put your recent update as an answer below and then mark it as the correct answer? That way this question won't look like it still needs an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I was trusting Chrome blindly. In the end the default zoom in Chrome was at 75%. So Chrome was the problem. Thx anyway :)